# How can you replace a column of a Dataset with another column or list?

Tags: replacement, dataset

Consider the dataset below with a "x" and a "CH 1" column:

[image]

How can I replace the "x" column with a new set of data? For example, how could I replace "x" with values starting from 0 and incrementing in steps of 0.033?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is probably by using `Part` assignment. Unfortunately, though, that doesn't work on `Dataset`s, so we have to convert back to `Normal` form to do so. Here's an example:

Create example dataset:

```
length = 10;
dat = Dataset[
  AssociationThread[{"x", "y"}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {length, 2}]
]
```

Create values to replace the `x` column:

```
newcolumnX = Range[length]
```

Use `Part` assignment to replace the column values; then convert back to `Dataset`:

```
dat = Normal[dat];
dat[[All, "x"]] = newcolumnX;
dat = Dataset[dat]
```

Alternatively, you can `Transpose` the dataset and then `Append`/`Prepend` a new column in one go (and then transpose back):

```
dat = Transpose[
  Prepend[Transpose[dat], "x" -> newcolumnX]
]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much. It's definitely convoluted which is a pity, but this also solves my ListLinePlot problem. It's not possible to use ListLinePlot[{dataset1, dataset2}], but it is possible to use ListLinePlot[{Normal[dataset1], Normal[dataset2]}]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `Dataset` as a copy of the old one with one column replaced. 
For completeness, here is some code that generates a test dataset similar to yours:

```
ds = Dataset[
  Inner[
    <|"x" -> #1, "ch1" -> #2|> &, 
    Range[2.5, 3.2, 0.1], 
    RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 8], 
    List
  ]
]
```

Now we wish to replace the "x" column with the new entries

```
newx = Subdivide[0, 0.033, 8]
```

We can do this in a single line:

```
ds = ds[MapIndexed[<|#1, "x" -> newx[[#2[[1]]]]|> &]]
```

The idea is to apply a function (`MapIndexed`) on the top level (first parameter of `ds`), such that we can access the entire table. Here, `#1` is the entire row and `#2` is the row-number wraped in `{}`. We use the fact that "If there are multiple elements with the same key [in an `Association`], all but the last of these elements are dropped", according to the help details. Tested in Mathematica 11.3.0.